# Clustering of vectors via inner product relationship

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis

This might be an odd question, but suppose I have a lot of vectors $a_i\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$ (not necessarily unit) and for some unit vector $u\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$ I find
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m a_{i1}^2(a_i^Tu)^2<\frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^m a_{i2}^2(a_i^Tu)^2.
$$

I feel like this must imply that $u\approx \pm e_2$ and that the $a_i$ are clustered around $\pm e_2$ as well, but I can't seem to find a way to quantify this.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: What are $a_{i1},a_{i2}$?

Comment: @AlexR. The first and second coordinates of the vector $a_i$.

Comment: So what happens if $a_i1^2$< (1/3) a_{i2}^2, say $a_{i1}=1$ and $a_{i2}=2$ for each vector $a_i$? Why would they cluster around $e_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u$ need not be near $\pm e_2$ at all.

Consider for example $u = e_3$ and $a_i$ a set of unit vectors lying fairly uniformly on an very small ellipse centered on $e_3$. (It makes sense to talk about an ellipse on the surface of a unit sphere, particularly if the ellipse is tiny so that the surface is nearly flat.)  If the major axis of the ellipses is in the $e_2$ direction (and necessarily the minor axis in the $e_1$ direction), and if the eccentricity is large, then the relationship presented will surely hold.  Yet $u$ is nowhere near the $e_2$ axis.

Comment: Thank you, I think I have a more specific question as a follow-up: your vectors all lie in the cone $\{\frac{a_{1}^2}{a_{2}^2} < \frac{1}{3}\}$.  Can we prove a more general statement of the form, "If such a $u$ exists, then at least $\alpha/m$ of the $a_i$ vectors must lie in this cone" ?

Comment: I suppose not, as you can take a set of vectors lying in the $xy$-plane which don't satisfy this, and then take $a_m$ to have $0$ first coordinate and an incredibly large second and third coordinate, and then take $u=a_m/\|a_m\|$.  Thanks!